# Subprocess.Call causing expansive fork and No Memory error

Tags: python-2.7

I am writing in Python for a very constrained Linux system and when I call `Subprocess.Call` with `shell=True` the system stalls with no memory available.

I had no idea that `Subprocess.Call` is not compatible with a fork/exec, it seems to me that the call is causing a heap duplication after forking.

Is this correct? If it is, how to overcame this?

Comment: To test, I have created a C module linked in the interpreter to call `system` directly, the result is that the C module takes 50% of the execution time and 95% of memory compared to the `subprocess.call`.

Comment: Have you tried `os.system`? The `subprocess` module is higher level, but that may be a bad thing when working in a very limited environment.

Comment: Didn't tested with os.system, but a C module calling system() resolved my problem. Yet, the question still is valid because I want to be sure that Subprocess.Popen is not compliant with fork/exec, where the fork cost is low.